# Having issues in Parsing Json File using Python code with lot of metadata without quotes

Tags: python, json, jsonparser

I have a JSON file with the following data - 
a:2:{ i:0;a:1:
                        {s:14:\"abcdefghiqwert\";s:3:\"123\"}
                i:1;a:2:
                        {s:14:\"akjhefghiqwert\";s:3:\"321\";
                        s:14:\"sdaderfrerferfe\";s:3:\"456\";
                        }
}

I would like to handle the metadata like s14, S3 separately
json.dumps doesn't do the proper encoding

How can I delete these unwanted metadata records using python?

Comment: What you have provided is simply a badly formatted JSON file. I'm not aware of any parser that would parse this JSON without raising an error. If your have such a parser then please provide code to show it's use, otherwise please refer to https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/ to see how to correctly format and construct a JSON file.

Comment: Actually this Json follows a pattern - a:2 (array of 2); s14 (string of 14 characters)
If I am able to delete this metadata my JSON will form nicely.
now the job is to find out out an efficient way of finding those tags which are without double quotes and deleting them

Comment: Yes, but you have `a:2` as an object key, whereas in JSON files only strings are valid as object keys; for example you could have `"a:2":{...`. That is what I'm meaning about being badly formed.

Comment: Well I am able to pull this off using -https://pypi.python.org/pypi/phpserialize
but now I am facing a problem wherein I have to convert the data into UTF - 8 encoding which results into a byte stream -{b'memory_use': b'0.5', b'memory_capacity': b'0.9', b'device_udate': b'2017/02/28 00:05:50'} (its my actual data); now I am unable to write this in the file because a file expects a string and I am unable to get rid of these unwanted b's.
any help would be most welcome-
error:    file.write(data1)
TypeError: 'dict' does not support the buffer interface

Comment: okay I got the solution for this problem also - if you see the phpserialize library they have mentioned the solution there - 
Another problem are unicode strings.  By default unicode strings are
encoded to 'utf-8' but not decoded on `unserialize`.  The reason for
this is that phpserialize can't guess if you have binary or text data
in the strings:
If you know that you have only text data of a known charset in the result.you can decode strings by setting `decode_strings` to True when calling loads:
    >>> loads(dumps(u'Hello W\xf6rld'), decode_strings=True)
    u'Hello W\xf6rld'